Use of lambda to perform basic multiplication
I am trying to do basic multiplication within all the individual elements of this list, but where am I going wrong with using lambda expression here?
inputData = [[2, 3], ["4", 7], [6, 4], [222, 25, 7], ["16", 22, "12", 6]]

Code I wanted to replicate:
for element in inputData:
    value = 1
    for multi in element:
        if isinstance(multi, str):
            multi = int(multi)
        value = value * multi
    print(value)

Code I am trying:
for element in inputData:
    value = 1
    for multi in element:
        multiplication = lambda multi: int(multi) * value if isinstance(multi, str) == True else multi * value
    print(multiplication(inputData))


You are executing your lambda only once, in your print statement. The loops are not doing anything (other than re-defining multiplication over and over). Also you don't really need a string check here. int() will also work with integers.

Your code defines a brand-new lambda on each iteration of its inner for loop, and then after the loop, it calls the final one of those lambdas.  All of the previous ones were completely irrelevant.  There is no possible way this could work, you're just throwing away most of your input data.  Why do you think a lambda is in any way useful here?

I thought of replacing the main function with a one-line lambda is all.. that's what I was trying to do. @jasonharper3

What makes you think you are going wrong in the first place?

Your second version never reassigns value like the first one does.

You could potentially use the lambda if you replaced the loops with calls to reduce().

lambda is not for shortening code, it is for creating an ad-hoc callable. A one-line version of the original string check would be value *= int(multi) if isinstance(multi, str) else multi. No lambda used. That being said, you really don't use the if ... as I mentioned above.

There wasn't anything wrong with 1st version @mkrieger1. I just wanted to replicate it using lambdas.

Don't think in terms of using lambdas. Think in terms of a type of loop that needs to call a function instead of executing a statement. Then the function could be a lambda.

map() and reduce() need a callback function, that's where lambda becomes useful. Although map() is not used much in python with lambda because list comprehensions are usually simpler. It's usually only used with named functions, e.g. map(int, list_of_things)

Sorry, by "in the first place" I didn't mean the first code. I meant: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_first_place. But anyway, why do you think that your code using lambda is wrong?

As already said, there's no real reason to use a lambda here, but another thing is: don't use named lambdas.

Thanks all, every answer is very helpful. I was thinking about lambdas the wrong way and now agree that there is no real need for a lambda here. I did however (just to close the loop) write a code using lambda that works fine. Here it is:
for element in inputData:
value = 1
for multi in element:
int_or_str = lambda multi: multi if isinstance(multi, int) == True else int(multi)
value = value*int_or_str(multi)
print(value)

The main reason to use a lambda here is so you can pass it to a higher-order function, namely, reduce:
import functools

for element in inputData:
    print(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a * int(b), element, 1))

But actually, since int and multiplication are pre-defined functions, you don't really need a lambda:
import functools
import operator

for element in inputData:
    print(functools.reduce(operator.mul, map(int, element)))

See map.
EDIT:
You could also use math.prod:
import math

for element in inputData:
    print(math.prod(map(int, element)))


If you can import those, surely you can also import math...

What @KellyBundy is saying is you can just use math.prod(map(int, element))

@wjandrea: Point taken. I didn't know about math.prod.
